# Magento programmatically appending code to template pages

Tags: templates, magento, footer

I am developing a Magento extension and would like to run some jQuery script in the footer of the html template.

I have manually edited page.xml layout file to load my jQuery source and manually edited the footer.phtml template file to test my code, but I now want to package it up into an extension. The question is how to do this within my extension configuration, to tell magento to load the new jQuery source library in the header, and to append code somewhere in the footer (or anywhere) in the magento generated theme html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a custom Magento Module
2. Use this module to add a customer Package Layout Update XML File
3. Use this Package Layout Update XML files to add a javascript src link to a (CDN?) jQuery, and add a custom block to the `before_body_end` block
4. Use this custom block to output your needed Javascript code
5. Use Magento Connect `System->Magento Connect->Package Extensions` to package up your customer Magento Module file, as well as any other files on the system you used (phtml template, jQuery files if not using a CDN, etc) into an Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use a static block? This way the client or yourself could update the jQuery right in the admin area without going into code. You could also add logic with multiple blocks if you needed. You can display a static block in a template like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('staticblockname') ?>
```

Otherwise you might want to read this tutorial on creating a module (which you call an extension): http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/